# Busting when splitting in blackjack

Tags: java

In my blackjack I have the players hit or stand and then to test to end the loop U have this code:

```
int runLoopCount1 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
        if (players[i].wantSplit = false){
                if(players[i].getStatus() == true){
                    runLoopCount1++;
                }
        }

        else if (players[i].wantSplit = true){
            if ((players[i].splits[0].busted == true||
                 players[i].splits[0].standed == true) &&
                (players[i].splits[1].busted== true ||
                 players[i].splits[1].standed == true)){ // null pointer here 
                        runLoopCount1++;
                }
            }
        }
                
   if(runLoopCount1 == players.length){
        runLoop = false;
   }
```

Now I get a `NullPointerException`. I don't know why though?

Comment: do you know what line the null pointer exception happens on?

Comment: This is an assignment: `if(players[i].wantSplit = false){`

Comment: i point out the line in the code just scroll to the right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really mean `if(players[i].wantSplit = false)` or `if(players[i].wantSplit == false)`
the same to `if(players[i].wantSplit = true)` or `if(players[i].wantSplit == true)`

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that `splits` in each player is not initialized properly.

```
players[i].splits[0].standed
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that you're trying to access an object that's not instantiated.  so for instance, if you do:

```
players[i].wantSplit
```

but `players[i]` was not instantiated, then a null pointer exception will be thrown